# GAEでTemplateファイルの参照に失敗する。

Tags: go, google-cloud

GoとGAEでアプリケーション開発をおこなっているんですが、以下のような構成で、テンプレートにデータを展開してメール送信を行いたいのですが、テンプレートファイルの読み込み部分で「no such file or directory」となってしまいうまくいきません。

なお、テストやローカル環境では正常に参照できている状態です。

```
# ディレクト
app
  L templates
     L emai.tpl
  L main.go
```

```
# ソースコード
t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/email.tpl")
if err != nil {
    return "", "", err
}
```

```
# app.yaml
main: ./app
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

このような場合、app.yamlを変更して静的ファイルとして配置する。バイナリに含めるなのどの方法を行えばいいのでしょうか？

ご存知の方いられましたら、ご教授いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `app.yaml` が置かれているディレクトリを起点とする相対パスになっている様なので、`Template.ParseFiles("app/templates/email.tpl")` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: metropolis様
ご教授いただいた設定でメール送信が成功いたしました！
大変助かりました。ありがとうございます。